# Table() function but for an adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I know this might sound trivial, but I looked everywhere and I could not find a function that is equivalent to table, but that works with an adjacency matrix create with the "igraph" package for network analysis.
The matrix is created using 2 vectors representing the edges of the network.
I tried using table but I get this error:

```
n <- get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(network2), directed=FALSE))

table(n)

Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

I just need a list of all the different values that appear in the matrix and how many times they appear each.
Thank you and sorry if this is dumb

Comment: I think `table` should work for a matrix - can you give more detail about what you are doing to produce that error?  And what is the result of `str(x)`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar `table` does work with a matrix, I cannot reproduce the error. To the OP: can you post sample data?

Comment: `m = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), nrow = 2); table(m)` works just fine. Do you have some other package masking the base `table` function? Or perhaps you don't have a `matrix`, but something else? Please share both the data you are using (or a small, illustrative sample of it - use `dput()` to create a copy/pasteable representation) and the command you are running (not just the error message you get).

Comment: sorry, I thought it was like any other matrix but probably it isn't. 
it is an adjacency matrix created to analyse links within a network.

Comment: You want `table(as.matrix(x))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar this is the result of str(x), but I'm not able to read it:

Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:15820] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:6664] 0 22 24 26 28 31 33 35 37 39 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6663 6663
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6663] "abbadia san salvatore" "piancastagnaio" "chianciano terme" "montalcino" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6663] "abbadia san salvatore" "piancastagnaio" "chianciano terme" "montalcino" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:15820] 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()

Comment: @AndrewGustar I'm not sure why, but it works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Antonio Despite the name, an igraph adjacency matrix is structured very differently from a normal matrix, which is basically just a vector.  It looks as if an adjacency matrix is structured as a sparse matrix, which is an efficient way of compressing a matrix if it has lots of zeros (which in practice it probably will).  The `as.matrix` converts it into the simpler format.

Comment: @AndrewGustar  Sure, this makes sense. Again, thank you very much